# Definition of $\epsilon$-upper envelope of a function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $u$ be a continuous function in an open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $H$ an open set such that $\bar{H}\subset \Omega$. We define , for $\epsilon >0$, the upper $\epsilon$-envelope of $u$ (with respect to $H$):

$u^{\epsilon}(x_{0})=\sup_{x \in \bar{H}}\Big\{u(x)+\epsilon -\frac{1}{\epsilon}|x-x_{0}|^{2}\Big\}$

For $x_{0} \in H$. The author says: *the graph of $u^{\epsilon}$ is the envelope of the graphs family  $\{P^{\epsilon}_{x}\}_{x \in \bar{H}}$ of concave paraboloids of opening $2/\epsilon$ and vertex $(x,u(x)+\epsilon)$.*

First, what is the envelope of the family of graphs? I considered the one dimensional case where $u(x)=x$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the concave "paraboloid" when $x_{0}=1$, for example is $P^{\epsilon}(x)=-\epsilon(x-1)^{2}+\epsilon +x$. I used a software program to draw the graph, varying the value of $\epsilon$, and I saw that the paraboloid is gradually crossing the whole line. But, I still do not understand the geometry of that definition.

Comment: should it be $P^\epsilon = x + \epsilon - \epsilon^{-1}(x-1)^2$ ? You should use your software to draw the graph varying $x$, rather than $\epsilon$, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the wrong scaling for  $P^\epsilon = x + \epsilon - \epsilon^{-1}(x-x_0)^2$ fooled you. The image to have in mind is a parabola below overshooting slightly (below for $\epsilon =\frac1{n+1}= 1/9 $ at $x_0=1$ in green and $x_0=2$ in orange).
[[image: <span class=]$P_\epsilon$ at $x=1$ (in green) and $x=2$ (in orange) for $\epsilon=\frac1{n+1}= 1/9$. Here $u=x$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHP4B.png)

The value is in this case simply a translation of u upward, and $u_\epsilon$ is also a line (a dashed line in the picture).

Comment: What is the slider in your picture indicating?

Comment: @LSpice thanks. My picture was the wrong way round. A new picture now with a legend.